# Weird MongoDB login error after backend shut down

Tags: node.js, mongodb, parse-server

Yesterday, OVH services went down, so a backend of an app of my own stopped working completely. Today, I tried starting up my app to see if everything was ok, and I was glad to see that the backend is already working, but... **my app didn't show any data**.

So I connected via PuTTy to my VPS to see my Node app was correctly working. I saw in pm2 (process manager for Node) that my app's instance was perfectly online. But in the Parse logs, I could see this error:

> {"message":"error getting auth for sessionToken","name":"MongoError" // more redundant error messages saying pretty much the same}

I could perfectly check that the current problem, is that my Node app can't connect the Mongo server, though the credentials are the same...

Some aclarations:

- The app backend and the MongoDB are stored in the same VPS.
- The Mongo credentials are the same; they didn't change at all.
- Tried restarting the node instance, but it won't change anything.

So, what's going on? How can I restart the mongo services and try again? And in case I need it... how can I change my mongo credentials?

Thank you!

EDIT: When I write "mongod" (it's a mongo service, right?) I get the following unexpected error:

```
mongod --help for help and startup options
2017-11-10T12:21:56.933+0100 [initandlisten] MongoDB starting : pid=7255 port=27017 dbpath=/data/db 64-bit host=vps332549
2017-11-10T12:21:56.934+0100 [initandlisten] db version v2.6.10
2017-11-10T12:21:56.935+0100 [initandlisten] git version: nogitversion
2017-11-10T12:21:56.935+0100 [initandlisten] OpenSSL version: OpenSSL 1.0.2g  1 Mar 2016
2017-11-10T12:21:56.935+0100 [initandlisten] build info: Linux lgw01-12 3.19.0-25-generic #26~14.04.1-Ubuntu SMP Fri Jul 24 21:16:20 UTC 2015 x86_64 BOOST_LIB_VERSION=1_58
2017-11-10T12:21:56.935+0100 [initandlisten] allocator: tcmalloc
2017-11-10T12:21:56.935+0100 [initandlisten] options: {}
2017-11-10T12:21:56.936+0100 [initandlisten] exception in initAndListen: 10296
*********************************************************************
 ERROR: dbpath (/data/db) does not exist.
 Create this directory or give existing directory in --dbpath.
 See http://dochub.mongodb.org/core/startingandstoppingmongo
*********************************************************************
, terminating
2017-11-10T12:21:56.936+0100 [initandlisten] dbexit:
2017-11-10T12:21:56.936+0100 [initandlisten] shutdown: going to close listening sockets...
2017-11-10T12:21:56.936+0100 [initandlisten] shutdown: going to flush diaglog...
2017-11-10T12:21:56.936+0100 [initandlisten] shutdown: going to close sockets...
2017-11-10T12:21:56.936+0100 [initandlisten] shutdown: waiting for fs preallocator...
2017-11-10T12:21:56.936+0100 [initandlisten] shutdown: lock for final commit...
2017-11-10T12:21:56.936+0100 [initandlisten] shutdown: final commit...
2017-11-10T12:21:56.936+0100 [initandlisten] shutdown: closing all files...
2017-11-10T12:21:56.937+0100 [initandlisten] closeAllFiles() finished
2017-11-10T12:21:56.937+0100 [initandlisten] dbexit: really exiting now
```

EDIT:
  Tried to do what the first answer said, though you can see here the result is not anywhere near good; the service just won't start, I don't know why. Also, how can I know where is my db root?

```
root@vps332549:~# service mongod status
● mongod.service
   Loaded: not-found (Reason: No such file or directory)
   Active: inactive (dead)
root@vps332549:~# service mongod restart
Failed to restart mongod.service: Unit mongod.service not found.
root@vps332549:~# mongod --dbpath=data/db/
2017-11-11T16:46:56.568+0100 [initandlisten] MongoDB starting : pid=6980 port=27017 dbpath=data/db/ 64-bit host=vps332549
2017-11-11T16:46:56.573+0100 [initandlisten] db version v2.6.10
2017-11-11T16:46:56.573+0100 [initandlisten] git version: nogitversion
2017-11-11T16:46:56.573+0100 [initandlisten] OpenSSL version: OpenSSL 1.0.2g  1 Mar 2016
2017-11-11T16:46:56.573+0100 [initandlisten] build info: Linux lgw01-12 3.19.0-25-generic #26~14.04.1-Ubuntu SMP Fri Jul 24 21:16:20 UTC 2015 x86_64 BOOST_LIB_VERSION=1_58
2017-11-11T16:46:56.573+0100 [initandlisten] allocator: tcmalloc
2017-11-11T16:46:56.573+0100 [initandlisten] options: { storage: { dbPath: "data/db/" } }
2017-11-11T16:46:56.573+0100 [initandlisten] exception in initAndListen: 10296
*********************************************************************
 ERROR: dbpath (data/db/) does not exist.
 Create this directory or give existing directory in --dbpath.
 See http://dochub.mongodb.org/core/startingandstoppingmongo
*********************************************************************
, terminating
2017-11-11T16:46:56.573+0100 [initandlisten] dbexit:
2017-11-11T16:46:56.573+0100 [initandlisten] shutdown: going to close listening sockets...
2017-11-11T16:46:56.573+0100 [initandlisten] shutdown: going to flush diaglog...
2017-11-11T16:46:56.573+0100 [initandlisten] shutdown: going to close sockets...
2017-11-11T16:46:56.573+0100 [initandlisten] shutdown: waiting for fs preallocator...
2017-11-11T16:46:56.573+0100 [initandlisten] shutdown: lock for final commit...
2017-11-11T16:46:56.574+0100 [initandlisten] shutdown: final commit...
2017-11-11T16:46:56.574+0100 [initandlisten] shutdown: closing all files...
2017-11-11T16:46:56.574+0100 [initandlisten] closeAllFiles() finished
2017-11-11T16:46:56.574+0100 [initandlisten] dbexit: really exiting now
root@vps332549:~# service mongod restart
Failed to restart mongod.service: Unit mongod.service not found.
root@vps332549:~# service mongod start
Failed to start mongod.service: Unit mongod.service not found.
root@vps332549:~#
```

Answer (score 1):

If you have already set up mongod as a service, then you should be able to check if it is running or not:

```
$ service mongod status
```

If it is simply inactive, just restart your service:

```
# service mongod restart
```

If it is not registered as a service, then the mongod command expects a dbpath parameter:

```
$ mongod --dbpath=data/db/
```

where `data/db/` is the path to the data directory of your database.

Comment: Not working at all... my mongod service is tottally down and won't get online again, as far as I've tried. Check my edit please!

Comment: Well then, I check your edit and you do not follow my advices: you need to pass to _mongod_ the right path of the app db as argument.

Comment: TGriff yeah, just realised. But how can I know where the db was located? I'm trying to locate it